# No reconoce SESSION en mi web al subir a un hosting

Tags: php, mysql, session, hosting

Tengo el siguiente código que se ejecuta cuando un usuario inicia sesión en mi sitio:

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
```

```
<?php 
    function secure($value){
        include 'conexion_be.php';
        $value = trim($value);
        $value = stripslashes($value);
        $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
        $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $value);
        return $value;
    }
    session_start();

    include_once 'conexion_be.php';
    $correo = secure($_POST['correo']);
    $pass = secure($_POST['pass']);
    $pass = hash('sha512', $pass);
    $status = "Online";
    if(!empty($_POST['correo']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])){
        $validar_login = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo='$correo' and pass='$pass'");

        if(mysqli_num_rows($validar_login) > 0){
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($validar_login)){
                if($correo = $row['correo'] && $pass = $row['pass']){
                    $_SESSION['correo'] = filter_var($row['correo'] , FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
                    $_SESSION['id'] = filter_var($row['id'] , FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
                    $_SESSION['user'] = filter_var($row['user'] , FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
                    $_SESSION['usuario'] = filter_var($row['usuario'] , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                    $_SESSION['avatar'] = filter_var($row['avatar'] , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                    $_SESSION['telefono'] = filter_var($row['telefono'] , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                    $_SESSION['pass'] = $row['pass'];
                    $_SESSION['nombre'] = filter_var($row['nombre'] , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                }
                $sql2 = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE usuarios SET status = '$status' WHERE id='".$row['id']."'");
            }
            header("location: ../index.php");
            exit;
        }else{
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
            echo 'setTimeout(function () {';
            echo 'swal("Usuario no encontrado!","Por favor verifica los datos introducidos e intentá nuevamente.","error").then( function(val) {';
            echo 'if (val == true) window.location.href = \'../acceso.php\';';
            echo '});';
            echo '}, 200);  </script>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'setTimeout(function () {';
        echo 'swal("¡Ups!","Parece que hay campos vacíos en tu formulario, por favor intentá nuevamente.","warning").then( function(val) {';
        echo 'if (val == true) window.location.href = \'../acceso.php\';';
        echo '});';
        echo '}, 200);  </script>';
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Este código funciona perfectamente al utilizar XAMPP, es decir puedo iniciar sesión de manera correcta y se me redirige a la página indicada en el código, es decir. index.php. Sin embargo, hoy subí mi página a un host y no sucede lo mismo. Sucede que en la base de datos sí se actualiza lo que sería el status del usuario (se muestra 'Online') tal y como sucede en XAMPP, pero no sucede la redirección ni tampoco reconoce la sesión, simplemente se muestra la página en la que está guardado el código de arriba pero totalmente en blanco. ¿Alguna idea de a qué se debe este problema? Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

- Asegúrate que  en el hosting este permitido el uso de sesiones.

Busca en el archivo php.ini   y debes tener una línea de la siguiente manera

```
session.use_cookies = 1
```

Imprime la variable `$_SESSION` completa para ver su contenido

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Cambia tu código:  el  `session_start();` debe ir justo después de la etiqueta de apertura `php`

```html
<?php 
session_start();

    function secure($value){
        include 'conexion_be.php';
        $value = trim($value);
        $value = stripslashes($value);
        $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
        $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $value);
        return $value;
    }
```

- Veo que no te muestra error: es posible que tengas el `Error logs` deshabilitado.

--------* EDITO * -----------

> Warning: Cannot modify header information – headers already sent

La causa más habitual de este problema es utilizar funciones que dan salida a información, por ejemplo con `print` o con `echo`, y luego intentar modificar las cabeceras, por ejemplo con `header()` o con `setcookie()`, ya que generan la situación descrita: se da salida a información, y esa información lleva sus respectivas cabeceras HTTP; no se pueden modificar después.

Solución:

1. Comprueba si hay líneas vacías al final de sus archivos .php Este es un problema común con algunas aplicaciones web. Elimine la línea vacía al final de su secuencia de comandos (después de la cadena final “?>” O “php>”)
2. Comprueba que no tengas un `echo` o `print` antes de utilizar la función `header()`

> Nota: Si buscas los fallos anteriores y no los encuentras puedes desesperarte. Y es que puede que no los tengas. La otra gran causa del error de modificación de cabeceras es el carácter BOM

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. No puedo modificar el php.ini por determinación del hosting, pero en sus especificaciones no indica que las sesiones se encuentren prohibidas. Habilité el error logs y ahora puedo ver lo siguiente: [22-Oct-2021 10:19:24 America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/c2410691/public_html/php/login_usuario_be.php:2) in /home/c2410691/public_html/php/login_usuario_be.php on line 41

Comment: he editado la respuesta

Comment: Gracias. Actualmente no me redirige a "index.php" porque detecta el session_start anteriormente llamado y eso imposibilita la redirección. Acabo de probar eliminando el session_start del código y efectivamente se concreta la redirección, pero como podría iniciar la sesión y a la vez que redirija a index.php? No logro comprender

Comment: session_start() solo debes llamarlo una vez a lo largo de todo tu sistema   digamos que la pagina principal de tu sistema web es index.php    tus primeras dos lines de ese documento serian   <?php   y session_start();    ñuego ya tendas habilitada la sesion en todo tu sistema

Comment: Entiendo. Cuando el usuario inicia sesión, se ejecuta el archivo "login_usuario.php" que incluye el código descripto en mi pregunta. Allí debería incluir el sessión_start()? Porque si ese es el caso luego no puedo hacer la redirección a index.php

Comment: La única forma que encontré de evitar esto fue utilizar redirecciones mediante echo, script javascript y window location, pero no se si esto sea óptimo